# Algorithm for optimal pairing strategy of items in two ordered lists while maintaining order

Tags: algorithm, list, weighted

I have the the following two ordered lists of items:

```
A = ["apples","oranges","bananas","blueberries"]
B = ["apples","blueberries","oranges","bananas"]
```

Each item has a score which is equal to the length of the string, so...

```
apples = 6 points
oranges = 7 points
bananas = 7 points
blueberries = 11 points
```

I want to create a list of pairs (A,B) that contain either the index from A or the index from B or both for a pair, without changing the sequential order that they appear in each list.

Each pair then has the score of its item, so by pairing items we halve the total score of both items. I want to get the combination of pairs that have the smallest score.

For example, in the two lists above, each item can be paired but some pairs prevent us from pairing others because we can't pair both without changing the order of one of the lists. For example we can't pair `"blueberries"` and also pair `"oranges"` as `"oranges"` comes **before** `"blueberries"` in one list but **after** it in the other. We could only pair one or the other. Each list could also have the same item multiple times.

The optimal result for the above problem is...

```
    +---+---+----------------+-------+
    | A | B | Value          | Score |
+---+---+---+----------------+-------+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | "apples"       | 6     |
+---+---+---+----------------+-------+
| 1 | - | 1 | "blueberries"  | 11    |
+---+---+---+----------------+-------+
| 2 | 1 | 2 | "oranges"      | 7     |
+---+---+---+----------------+-------+
| 3 | 2 | 3 | "bananas"      | 7     |
+---+---+---+----------------+-------+
| 4 | 3 | - | "blueberries"  | 11    |
+---+---+---+--------+-------+-------+
                     | Total | 42    |
                     +-------+-------+
```

I think the answer is along the lines of:

1. Find the pairs
2. Split those pairs into possible groups of pairs
3. Calculate the group with the greatest weight

I can determine which pairs exclude which other pairs visually by joining the pairs from one list to another, if that join intersects another join it excludes it. I'm not sure how this would be done programmatically though.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I think the question is a bit confusing, since you put only the indices in the example, then we have to go through several level of translation to understand why the number in the bracket.

Comment: Apologies, I will try edit the question to help out. I've been trying to simplify the problem as much as possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've split the problem into sub problems... The test to check it is all working as expected:

```py
# These are the two lists I want to pair
a = [ "apples"
    , "oranges"
    , "bananas"
    , "blueberries" ]

b = [ "apples"
    , "blueberries"
    , "oranges"
    , "bananas" ]

# This is the expected result
expected = [ (0, 0)
           , (None, 1)
           , (1, 2)
           , (2, 3)
           , (3, None) ]

# Test the function gets the correct result
assert expected == get_indexes_for_best_pairing(a, b)
print("Tests pass!")
```

---

### 1. Create a list of all of the pairs

Create a map of the values from list A with the list of the associated indices...

```py
def map_list(list):
    map = {}
    for i in range(0, len(list)):

        # Each element could be contained multiple times in each
        # list, therefore we need to create a sub array of indices
        if not list[i] in map:
            map[list[i]] = []

        # Add the index onto this sub array
        map[list[i]].append(i)
    return map
```

The `map` would look like...

```py
{ "apples": [0]
, "oranges": [1]
, "bananas": [2]
, "blueberries": [3] }
```

Find all of the pairs by cross referencing list B...

```py
def get_pairs(a, b):
    map = map_list(a)
    pairs = []
    for i in range(0, len(b)):
        v = b[i]
        if v in map:
            for j in range(0, len(map[v])):
                pairs.append((map[v][j], i))
    return pairs
```

The `pairs` are as follows...

```py
[ (0, 0)
, (3, 1)
, (1, 2)
, (2, 3) ]
```

---

### 2. Get the scores for each pair

Simply loop through the pairs and look up the value in the original list:

```py
def get_pairs_scores(pairs, a):
    return [len(a[i]) for i, _ in pairs]
```

---

### 3. Create a list of pairs that each pair excludes

For each pair find the other pairs it excludes...

```py
def get_pairs_excluded_by_pair(pairs, i):

    # Check if the context pair excludes the pair, if both of the
    # pairs indexes are greater or less than the other pair, then
    # the pairs are inclusive and we will have a positive number, 
    # otherwise it will be negative
    return [j for j in range(0, len(pairs)) 

        # If the current context pair is also the pair we are comparing
        # skip to the next pair
        if i != j 
        and ((pairs[i][0] - pairs[j][0]) * (pairs[i][1] - pairs[j][1]) < 0)]

def get_pairs_excluded_by_pairs(pairs):
    excludes = []
    for i in range(0, len(pairs)):
        excludes.append(get_pairs_excluded_by_pair(pairs, i))
    return excludes
```

The `pairs_excludes` method will return...

```py
[ []
, [2, 3]
, [1]
, [1] ]
```

---

### 4. Calculate the total cumulative score for each pair minus the pairs it excludes

*Plus the score of the pairs that are excluded by the pairs it excludes... etc, etc.*

Use a depth first algorithm to traverse a acyclic graph of excludes to get the cumulative score for each pair... This is the meat of what we need to do...

```py
def get_cumulative_scores_for_pairs(pairs, excludes, scores):
    cumulative = []

    # For each pair referenced in the excludes structure we create a new
    # graph which starting from that pair. This graph tells us the total
    # cumulative score for that pair
    for i in range(0, len(pairs)):
        score = 0

        # Keep a reference of the nodes that have already been checked by 
        # in this graph using a set. This makes the graph acyclic
        checked = set()
        checked.add(i)

        # We keep a note of where we are in the graph using this trail
        # The pairs relate to the index in the pair_excludes. if pair
        # first is x and pair second is y it refers to pair_excludes[x][y]
        trail = []

        # We start the current x, y to be the first exclude of the current
        # start node
        current = [i, 0]

        # Sorry, tree traversal... Might not very readable could  
        # be done with recursion if that is your flavour
        while True:

            # Get the referenced excluded node
            if len(excludes[current[0]]) > current[1]:
                j = excludes[current[0]][current[1]]

                # We do not want to calculate the same pair twice
                if not j in checked:

                    # It has not been checked so we move our focus to 
                    # this pair so we can examine its excludes
                    trail.append(current)

                    # We mark the pair as checked so that we do
                    # not try and focus on it if it turns up again
                    checked.add(j)
                    current = [j, 0]

                    # We perform a trick here, where when we traverse 
                    # down or up a layer we flip the sign on the score.
                    # We do this because the score for pairs that we
                    # exclude need to be subtracted from the score whereas
                    # scores for pairs that we now can include because of
                    # that exclude need to be added to the score.
                    score = -score

                # It the pair has already been checked, check its 
                # next sibling next time around
                else:
                    current[1] += 1

            # There are no more nodes to check at this level
            else:

                # We subtract the cumulative score from the score of the 
                # pair we are leaving. We do this when we traverse back up 
                # to the parent or as the last step of each graph finally 
                # subtracting the total cumulative score from the start node 
                # score.
                score = scores[current[0]] - score
                if len(trail):

                    # Pop the next item on the trail to become our context
                    # for the next iteration
                    current = trail.pop()

                # Exit criteria... The trail went cold
                else:
                    break

        # Add the score to the array
        cumulative.append(score)
    return cumulative
```

This method should return an array that looks like...

```py
[ 6
, -3
, 3
, 3 ]
```

---

### 5. Pick only the best pairs

We need to then store the index with the score so that we can sort on score without losing the index.
Sort the cumulative scores in order we create a list of the indices `indices`...

```py
# Sort pairs by score retaining the index to the pair
arr = sorted([(i, cumulative[i]) 
    for i in range(0, len(cumulative))], 
    key=lambda item: item[1])
```

It looks like...

```py
[ (1, -3)
, (2, 3)
, (3, 3)
, (0, 6) ]
```

Pick the top scoring items deleting the excluded items as we go, this way we retain the best pairs and discard the worst...

```py
def get_best_pairs(a, b):
    pairs = get_pairs(a, b)
    excludes = get_pairs_excluded_by_pairs(pairs)
    scores = get_pairs_scores(pairs, a)
    cumulative = get_cumulative_scores_for_pairs(pairs, excludes, scores)

    # Sort pairs by score retaining the index to the pair
    arr = sorted([(i, cumulative[i]) 
        for i in range(0, len(cumulative))], 
        key=lambda item: item[1])

    # Work through in order of scores to find the best pair combination
    top = []
    while len(arr):
        topitem = arr.pop()
        top.append(topitem[0])

        # Remove the indices that are excluded by this one
        arr = [(i, score) 
            for i, score in arr 
                if i not in excludes[topitem[0]]]

    # Sort the resulting pairs by index
    return sorted([pairs[i] for i in top], key=lambda item: item[0])
```

Our `top` list would look like, where the pair with the index `1` has been dropped because it was low scoring and excluded by higher scoring pairs...

```py
[ (0, 0)
, (1, 2)
, (2, 3) ]
```

---

### 6. Build the result

Sort the selected pairs and build the result by incrementing each index to the next pair. When we run out of pairs increment until we reach the end of each list...

```py
def get_indexes_for_best_pairing(a, b):
    pairs = get_best_pairs(a, b)
    result = [];
    i = 0
    j = 0
    next = None
    pair = None
    while True:

        # This is the first loop or we just dropped a pair into the result
        # vector so we need to get the next one
        if next == None:

            # Get the next pair and we will increment the index up to this
            if len(pairs):
                next = pairs.pop(0)
                pair = next

            # No more pairs increment the index to the end of both lists
            else:
                next = (len(a), len(b))
                pair = None

        # We increment the index of the first list first
        if i < next[0]:
            result.append((i, None))
            i += 1

        # We increment the index of the second list when first has reached
        # the next pair
        elif j < next[1]:
            result.append((None, j))
            j += 1

        # If both indexes are fully incremented up to the next pair and we
        # have a pair to add we add it to the result and increment both
        # clearing the next parameter so we get a new one next time around
        elif pair != None:
            result.append((pair[0], pair[1]));
            i += 1
            j += 1
            next = None

        # We reached the end
        else:
            break
    return result
```

And finally our result would look like...

```py
[ (0, 0)
, (None, 1)
, (1, 2)
, (2, 3)
, (3, None) ]
```

Comment: For large sets this will be prohibitive O(n2), there are likely other solutions (looking at diff libraries and LCS solutions) that may yield satisfactory results.

Answer (score 1):

Note, my answer assumes that there are only 2 lists and that items can be at most one time in each list.

The first thing you do is to build a map/dictionary with the item as the key and a pair of integers as the value. This map will contain the indices of one item in both arrays. Run through the first list and put the index in the first value of the pair and -1 in the second. Do the same for the second list but obviously put the index in the second value. Something like this :

```
pairs = map<string, pair<int, int>>

i = 0
while i < A.Length
    pairs[A[i]].first = i
    pairs[A[i]].second = -1
    i++
i = 0
while i < B.Length
    pairs[B[i]].second = i
    i++
```

Now, you have to establish what are the possible pair combinations you can do. This pseudo code creates a list of all the possible combinations :

```
i = 0
while i < A.Length
    j = i
    index = -1
    combination = list<pair>
    while j < A.Length
        pair = pairs[A[j]]
        if pair.second > index
            combination.add(pair)
            index = pair.second
        j++
    combinations.add(combination)
    i++
```

Now, all that's left is to weigh the possible combinations but don't forget to include the items that weren't paired.

**EDIT**

What I'm thinking now is to build a map of all the possible pairs for each item. Something that would yield the following result.

```
oranges: [0,2][0,5][5,2][5,5][0,-1][-1,2][5,-1][-1,5]
apples: [1,1][1,-1][-1,1]
bananas: [2,3][2,-1][-1,3]
...
```

Using the exclude logic, we can group these pairs and produce a map of list of list of pairs.

```
oranges: [0,2][5,-1][-1,5], [0,5][5,-1][-1,2], ..., [0,-1][5,-1][-1,2][-1,5]
apples: [1,1], [1,-1][-1,1]
...
```

Now, only one list of pairs per item can be used in the result output and some lists exclude each other between different items. What's left is to come up with an algorithm to weigh each possibilities.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that an item can be included multiple times in each list, but you are correct only two lists will be merged at a time. I will update the question...

Comment: Also the answer assumes both of the lists are the same length, the logic for getting all combinations of pairs will not work for `["apples","oranges","blueberries"]` and `["apples","blueberries","oranges"]` as it will fail to find the valid combination `apples` and `blueberries`, I think it is close though so thanks, I've updated my question.

Comment: I also noticed my logic to get the possible combinations is flawed. I'll try to come up with another solution.